# one thread to exit them all

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, winapi

I have a main program that generates a few threads (using a while loop with accept() to get clients), and one that all it has to do is "listen to the keyboard" and when the user enters the word exit it will close the entire program.
first, the main program create the listening thread, then it enters a while loop that accept the clients. **even if the listening thread get the exit input the loop is still stuck on accept.**

i don't have to use a seperate thread to listen to the keyboard but i could'nt find a none blocking way that would work.

the listening thread:

```
DWORD WINAPI ListenService(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    char buffer[5];
    if (EOF == scanf("%s", buffer))
    {
        printf("faile get word from keyboard\n");
    }
    if (buffer[4] != '\0')
        strcat(buffer, "\0");
    if (STRINGS_ARE_EQUAL(buffer, "exit"))
    {
        return 999;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

in the main code:

```
ThreadListen = CreateThread(NULL,0,ListenService,NULL,0,&(ThreadId));   
while(1)
{
    SOCKET AcceptSocket = accept(MainSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (AcceptSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Accepting connection with client failed, error %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        CleanupWorkerThreads();
        WSACleanup();
    }
    printf("Client Connected.\n");
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but the [CreateThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread) documentation has the following to say: *"A thread in an executable that calls the C run-time library (CRT) should use the `_beginthreadex` and `_endthreadex` functions for thread management rather than `CreateThread` and `ExitThread`"*.

Comment: Call ExitProcess().

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways you can handle this.

You can abort a blocked `accept()` by simply closing the listening socket.

Or, you can use `select()` with a short timeout to detect when a new client is waiting before then calling `accept()`. You can check your exit condition in between calls to `select()`. Just be aware that there is a small race condition where a client *may* disconnect between the time `select()` and `accect()` are called, so `accept()` *may* still block, if there are no more clients waiting.

Or, you can get rid of your threads and just use non-blocking sockets in a single thread, checking your exit condition periodically in between socket operations.

Or, you can use asynchronous sockets, using `WSACreateEvent()`, `WSAEventSelect()`, and `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()` to detect socket activity. Then you can create an addition event to wait on for when the exit condition happens.

Or, you can use an I/O Completion Port to handle socket activity, and then you can post a custom exit packet into the IOCP queue using `PostQueuedCompletionStatus()` to "wake up" any waiting threads.

Comment: i think the select option can be the solution i'm looking for, i tried reading on select in windows doc but could find the way to use it to detect a new client i waiting, and chance you can explain about that option more?

Comment: @dinohayon a listening socket is in a readable state when it has a client waiting to be accepted. So simply call `select()` asking for readability, using an `fd_set` containing the listening socket. If the listening socket is readable, `FD_ISSET()` will report true for that socket in the `fd_set` after `select()` exits.